# Post an update(message) twitter

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter

How can I post a message to twitter using only javascript (no serverside authentification).

For example I have a form with username, password, and a text field and a submit button.

I want to use it on the backend of a website.

I have read this, http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update but I do not know how to handle the authentification of the username.

(I know that it involves many security risks doing it this way)

Comment: Note that the username/password based API will be shut down in some days. You should look into using OAuth instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either use the javascript twitter api helper at 
http://sources.disruptive-innovations.com/twitterHelper/tags/latest/TwitterHelper.html

or the far easier way is to use the @anywhere api from twitter
(http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin)

Comment: I have already tried twitterhelper but there is also a problem with the authentification I think. I get unauthorised as the response.

And some parameters are not really explained. Do you have an example to it?

Comment: \@anywhere is now deprecated. See the Sunsetting \@Anywhere post: https://dev.twitter.com/blog/sunsetting-anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Nikolaus Gradwohl!

I made a little example for myself.

https://gist.github.com/2844705

Answer (score 0):

A very helpful post : http://oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms

Hope this helps ! Bye !