# how to post a tweet without tweetBox, in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

like FB.api('/me/feed','post',{message: "good"}, function(){}) in facebook api,
once the user click the button on my app (not twitter button), trigger a function to post the tweet.

I want to know, is it possible, and how to implement it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twitter does not have a JavaScript SDK. You will either have to write your own JavaScript that makes a request to your own server which performs the request to Twitter or use [Web Intents](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/intents#tweet-intent).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with limitations via tweetbox:  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome#tweetbox

Comment: You can even do it like this: T.Status.update("Hello world");
Example here: https://groups.google.com/group/twitter-dev-anywhere/browse_thread/thread/9101e0dde52a0aa3/ebd945f3ec636938?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

I needed to figure this one out as well.  I managed to find the answer in another thread ( [Post an update(message) twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466906/post-an-updatemessage-twitter) ).  Then I made a quick gist to try it out.

https://gist.github.com/2844705

Actually, ialphan's comment has the answer.